# Feasability of an OGAS/Cybersyn-style Socialist Internet In An Alternate 1930s

Tags: science-based, alternate-history

OGAS and Project Cybersyn were both plans in socialist countries for an internet-style system that would be used to coordinate central planning. In this alternate timeline, World War 1 has never happened, and Julius Edgar Lillenfield's transistor was successfully made in late 1931. Los Angeles is independent due to colonial disputes, similar to the Free City of Danzig. A socialist president who wants to create a socialist internet system is elected. Would such a thing be possible?

EDIT: This was a bad question, so I am closing it.

Comment: Hello @Trurl50, welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. This Q violates a number of rules you'll find in [help/on-topic] and [help/dont-ask]. If you think about it, our goal is to help you create and consistently use rules for a fictional world of your own creation. By definition, what you're asking for is possible. It's your world. If you're asking *could this really have happened?* the answer is either no, because it didn't happen or yes, because all you did was advance the timeline 30 years. (\*Continued\*)

Comment: ... As written this Q should be closed. Before the crew starts getting involved, can you ask a *specific* question with a *solvable problem?*

Comment: BTW, Lilienfeld invented the FET in 1925. Are you sure 1931 is the date you want to choose? To advance computational tech as fast as you'd need, Someone would have needed to invent the FET (and the world a bunch of other tech involving manufacturing) by at least about 1902. That could have been Lilienfeld, but he would have only been 20 years old.

Comment: Can you tell us any part of this that you think wouldn't be possible? The whole "World War 1 never happened" part of it would require a significant rewrite in history, but you can make almost any timeline happen with enough tinkering. As is, the question is likely to be closed as not having enough focus.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Why?

Putting aside my personal issues with all things Socialist - there are 3 things you need for such a system:

1: a functional Computer.

Well, you haven't had WW2 and Alan Turing hasn't been tasked with cracking Lorenz yet. Without that, Computers aren't really a thing. Even if you want something like the Z1 (which was purely mechanical) - that was created at the end of the 1930s and wasn't reliable.

2: Network protocols.

Let's assume we have 2 functional computers - we string a bit of cable between them, should be good to go, right? Wrong.

You need a means by which the two computers can talk to each other. These days that is either TCP or UDP, but TCP didn't exist until the 1970s, it's precursor - NCP didn't exist until the 1960s.

That gives us ~20 years from the first 'Computers', to the first 'Computer networking'

3: Networking equipment.

You can argue that in some way this already exists in the 1930s with telephone switches and in many ways, this is the easiest issue to overcome as Copper Cabling exists - but there's a difference between simply re-purposing analogue phone lines (which to be fair was what they initially did) with proper networking (which didn't really happen until you get a reliable Network protocol e.g. TCP)

In short: No WW2 means no computers, No Computers means no one has any need to develop Networking Protocols, and without those two things, no one bothers to figure out proper networking.

Comment: Ignore me, I'm an idiot. Well, ignore some of me. I suspect the dating the OP gave the invention of the FET suggests he/she doesn't quite understand what they're asking, so that last comment about not answering questions that aren't well-asked is still valid.